K8s controller without a closed control loop is bad idea?
First time asking a question here.
My company has built a k8s controller but without what i would assume is required for a k8s controller to be reliable.
User applys CRs, controller reads them and sends config msg to legacy component(call it component X) we are configuring.
We have listers for svc, pod,endpoints, and our CRs. But we have no ability to query the component we are configuring. Which means if there is ever any desync of what our controller thinks the component x is configured with and what it is actually configured with, there is no ability to recover. The only solution for our customers is to manually restart the component x pod. Unsurprisingly bugs are a huge issue.
I want to make the case that this design will not work. Maybe we can fix all the simple bugs but our controller will always be very fragile, and there will be cases that are just unrecoverable and we will never be able to fix. I want to make the case that we need to be able to query component x so that we can actually follow the controller pattern or else the product will always be bug riddled and fragile.
Can someone help me understand how to make that case, or if I'm wrong and actually this design can work, I'd love to hear how. Thanks
I would expect a k8s controller need to follow the following pattern, look at CR, look at state of component that the controller is configuring, if state is not what CR says it should be, take action.
Instead we just have, look at CR, send configuration msg. And the different CRDS and the configuration they produce have wildly complex dependencies on each other.
